# How do I put header & data in the Tar file format?

Tags: unix, tar

I am trying to write a pure C++ tar file manipulation library. Can one simply put the tar headers followed by the data, with nothing special in between, I have looked through Wikipedia, and the gnu site and have come up with everything I need except for a few things, including this. I am trying to use the (new?) ustar format.

Comment: I think this would fit better in SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BSD [tar(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=5) manual page could be considered authoritative.

Related: [libarchive-formats(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libarchive-formats&sektion=5), [cpio(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpio&sektion=5), the [libarchive](http://libarchive.github.com/) library which you could maybe write a C++ wrapper for

Comment: The tar format is actually easy enough that a pure c++ module is not out of the question. But the page cleared up my question, Thank you!